# find max value in multiple split loops

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I try to isolate the one maximum value from 4 split loops and have so far not unraveled the mystery.

The recordset XlsRecWeeks comes from an excel worksheet field [Scheduled Weeks] containing weeknumbers as values like 
6,
7,
6-22,
9-12;14-24

and so on, representing either one week, a period between two weeks or even several periods of multiple weeks in each field.

I managed to split the fields into an array of single weeks, and i need to determine the single highest weeknumber of all the values in the resulting array.

May i ask for an advice?

Here's the code so far

```
do while not XlsRecWeeks.EOF
  If not isnull(XlsRecWeeks("scheduled weeks")) Then
  weekgroups=Split(XlsRecWeeks("scheduled weeks"), ";")
  if ubound(weekgroups) > 0 then
    for each weekintervals in weekgroups
    weekinterval=Split(weekintervals, "-")
        if ubound(weekinterval)> 0 then
        for weeknrs = weekinterval(0) to weekinterval(1)
     Response.Write weeknrs & "<br />"
    next
        else
     Response.Write weeknrs & "<br />"
        end if
next
else
    weekinterval=Split(XlsRecWeeks("scheduled weeks"), "-")
        if ubound(weekinterval)> 0 then
        for weeknrs = weekinterval(0) to weekinterval(1)
     Response.Write weeknrs & "<br />"
        next
        else
     Response.Write XlsRecWeeks("scheduled weeks") & "<br />"
        end if
end if
else
end if
XlsRecWeeks.movenext
loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a variable (maxWeek) to contain the max week number, initially set low, and a function to compare whatever week numbers you get from the data to this value (checkMax). All you do is call the function any time you get a new week number and at the end of the process the value of the maxWeek variable is the highest week number in the data set. You could get funky by putting the week numbers into an array and sorting it but that would be overkill for what you are doing.

Couple of notes of caution: 1) the code is not tested but its not hard to understand and you seem competent; 2) note that you need the cInt() or cLng() function to force the comparison of the week number to be numeric - if you neglect this you will get odd results. 2) I reformated / indented the code but the logic is as your original - you will find that your code is easier to read and pass on if you format and space it for readability and comment it for explanation - worth considering as otherwise you'll never get promoted as all the know-how will rest with you [Assuming you are new to coding - sorry if preaching]

Edit: Error in first edit - I used the `return` which is an invalid verb in VBS. As everyone knows, to return a value from a function you have to set the function name as if it were a variable. CheckMax() function altered.

Edit: Corrected use of val() to cInt() function. The val() function is a VB6 function that did not get ported to VBS.

```
dim maxWeek
maxWeek = -1 
do while not XlsRecWeeks.EOF
    If not isnull(XlsRecWeeks("scheduled weeks")) Then
        weekgroups=Split(XlsRecWeeks("scheduled weeks"), ";")
        if ubound(weekgroups) > 0 then
            for each weekintervals in weekgroups
                weekinterval=Split(weekintervals, "-")
                if ubound(weekinterval)> 0 then
                    for weeknrs = weekinterval(0) to weekinterval(1)
                        Response.Write weeknrs & "<br />"
                        maxWeek = checkMax(Cint(weeknrs)), maxWeek)                 
                    next
                else
                    weeknrs = weekinterval(0)   
                    Response.Write weeknrs & "<br />"
                    maxWeek = checkMax(Cint(weeknrs)), maxWeek)                 
                end if
            next
        else
            weekinterval=Split(XlsRecWeeks("scheduled weeks"), "-")
            if ubound(weekinterval)> 0 then
                for weeknrs = weekinterval(0) to weekinterval(1)
                    Response.Write weeknrs & "<br />"
                    maxWeek = checkMax(Cint(weeknrs)), maxWeek)                 
                next
             else
                Response.Write XlsRecWeeks("scheduled weeks") & "<br />"
                weeknrs = XlsRecWeeks("scheduled weeks")
                maxWeek = checkMax(Cint(weeknrs)), maxWeek)                 
             end if
        end if
    end if

    XlsRecWeeks.movenext

loop
' maxWeek now holds max week value.
```

response.write(maxWeek)

```
function checkMax(theVal, currentMax)

checkMax = currentMax 
if theVal > checkMax then 
    checkMax = theVal
end if

end function
```

Comment: Thanks VW, and I appreciate your comments - are slowly breaking new ground in coding. i changed val() to Cint(), But i cannot use "return" - get "variable undeclared" and the attempt to response.write(currentMax) as a final value of all the spilts compared are empty. What do I miss?

Comment: @MortenWB Apologies been doing a lot of javascript where return IS allowed. Now edited to correct to VBS. Only the checkMax function was altered so cut & paste just that.

Comment: super, thanks! the code does excactly the right thing now, using Cint() instead of val() and able to response.write(maxWeek) where needed. And no apology needed - you have been very helpful.

Comment: Thanks - accepted your edit and added a bit of my own.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again - I thought it would be easy to apply the same method for finding the minimum just checking if theVal < currentMin (adding a min-line to the code), but i fail to make that work. May I ask for your input, although it ought to be a new question?

Comment: For min just make sure you set the min variable to something high like 999999 before the loop starts. Other than that it should work.

Comment: Saved my day - again! I feel like a newbie.

Comment: @MortenWB glad to help. Also you may not know that there is a little vote up button beside these comments and when you click it the author gets a reputation point. SO feel free to click if a comment helps - its a way of marking the valuable comments.